# Symfony nested services

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

Can Symfony DI config file create a service of services? By that I mean something in the spirit of the following gist :

```yaml
services:
    authenticator:
        class: Acme\Foo
        arguments: [@foo, @parser.users]
    parsers: # not valid, this would not compile
        users:
            class: Csfd\Parsers\User
        messages:
            class: Csfd\Parsers\Message
```

I would like to define all `parsers` as services, but I also want to have them under a `parsers` branch, so it's obvious they do not actually represent the (also existing) `User` or `Message` entities.

In the example, `@parser.users` would resolve to instance of `Csfd\Parsers\User`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible by default. The "problem" lies here: [YamlFileLoader.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.4/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php#L108).

As you can see, it doesn't support nesting and treats first level under "services" as service id.

You could create your own YamlFileLoader which would have support for this and use it in your bundle's extension class.

Comment: Alright, thanks, will do. What a shame it's a private method.

Comment: For future reference: simple patch of YamlFileLoader works well enough https://gist.github.com/Mikulas/8004470

Comment: Indeed it is. Though they made `parseDefinitionNode` private so extending and overriding it can't be done and editing it is not an option since it's in vendors and will be overwritten on first update.